# How to create thumb button VB.net

Tags: thumbnails, windows-media-player

Excuse me, I'm developing Music player and I want to create thumb button same as Windows media player. How to create it? Thanks

Comment: This would be a better question if you give more context and explain what you have already tried.

Comment: I have tried import System.Windows.Shell and I have tried to search information about it but I don't know how to use Shell to create thumb button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i been looking for the same answer, so far no luck

but i found these.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Scroll down to Remarks.

there are example provided by Microsoft how to create a small play button and stop button.

Hope that's helpful